# Wicket - runtime class reloading

Tags: java, class, runtime, wicket, reloading

I have classical complaint - rebuilding and reloading the web app takes too long. I want to compile the classes (preferrably from the IDE) or change a static file and let the server check what changed and act approprietly (reload the class/file).

What are my options for Wicket + JDK 1.6 ? I'd prefer Jetty, but Tomcat, JBoss AS or others are good, too.

I am not using the `ReloadingWicketFilter` since I use `mvn jetty:run-exploded` because it's the simplest way to run my app with desired configuration, and jetty plugin does not (?) support using that.

Thanks,
Ondra

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to configure Wicket in development mode by adding this init param to Wicket's filter in web.xml:

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>configuration</param-name>
    <param-value>development</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Another productivity booster is JRebel which reloads classfile changes (well, most of them) on the fly.