# Code change reloading in Wicket

Tags: wicket, classloader, reload

I've started to work with [Wicket](http://wicket.apache.org/). When I make changes to the HTML templates, that becomes visible right away.

But when I make changes to the code, I need to restart Jetty. I'm running in `DEVELOPMENT` mode (at least that's what the big fat warning in the log says) and I have installed the `ReloadingWicketFilter` as per this question: [Wicket - runtime class reloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3082312/wicket-runtime-class-reloading)

My guess is that this behavior is because I make all changes in the constructor of my pages and Wicket doesn't create a new page when I reload.

I've browsed the Wicket examples but there is no example which shows how to build a Wicket page *without* adding all components in the constructor or how to tell Wicket to create a new page for every request or how to tell Wicket to create a new Page.

Answer (score 4):

I am using mvn jetty:run and this config in the pom.xml:

```
 <plugin>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <!-- to be used in combination with netbeans compile on save feature -->
                <scanTargets>
                    <scanTarget>target/classes/</scanTarget>
                </scanTargets>
                <scanIntervalSeconds>1</scanIntervalSeconds>
            </configuration>
 </plugin>
```

And my IDE (NetBeans) is configured that it compiles on save... then I can make a change switch to the browser and hit reload ... and the changes were applied + jetty was reloaded

Or use the commercial app [jrebel](http://www.zeroturnaround.com/jrebel/)

Comment: That looks promising; it should work the same way in Eclipse.

Comment: Yes I think so. It should work even for all ('lightweight') java webframeworks. see also my link to jrebel

Answer (score 0):

I think that last paragraph can be addressed by overriding Component's onInitialize() method.

See [http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/Component.html#onInitialize()](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/Component.html#onInitialize%28%29)

Regards,

Marek

Comment: What happens if I add a new component to the same ID several times?

Answer (score 0):

In IntelliJ, run the Start application through debugging.  As you make changes to Java and compile, IntelliJ reloads the class through HotSpot.  The changes become available in your application.

You are of course limited to HotSpot"s limitation of only being able to (for example) create new classes and change method bodies.